# working with raw files using photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, raw-format

I just need the basics, I have made a raw jpeg with my phone (saving raw) but I dont see any difference, What is the benefit in saving raw images and how to handle them using photoshop? Here is the sample photo:

[image]

as a test i would like to remove the background altering the depth of the focus, I'm not sure if this is what raw is for really.

Comment: I recommend that you do a search and read up on raw image format. In essence raw is processed as little as possible by the camera and contains more data than for instance JPG, making it possible (and necessary) to process and adjust the image a lot more than a compressed format allows. I think of it as a digital negative. What you want to test is not easier than on other image formats, that's not what raw is for.

Comment: There is no such thing as a RAW jpeg.  A RAW is an unprocessed image file. The image you shared is just a regular jpeg.

Comment: @BillyKerr should I look in my phone memory for a file named .raw or something like that?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what format your camera app is using - there are dozens of RAW formats. Does the software you are using not have any documentation or a website for help?

Comment: @BillyKerr I did it with a S6 turning on the option for raw, was expection to find something in my phone, then I found this big sized JPG and though it was a raw file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jpeg is not raw, jpeg is the result of a process called raw development.The original raw image needs easily 20 times more memory space than a jpeg due lack of compression and much larger brightness range.

Phones and other modern cameras have advanced raw developing software that can produce good jpgs. Ordinary displays cannot show more info than a good jpg contains, so when you watch an image which is stored as raw, you actually watch the result of the development.

To get some benefits you must get the raw image as a file to a proper raw development software. Photoshop's Camera Raw knows hundreds of different cameras (=knows, how to develop their raw files). If you're lucky, it knows also your camera.

Adobe gives a list of compatible cameras, which grows continuously, if you have a new Photoshop which is still developed. Old pre-CC Photoshops will not get updates, but that has a workaround: Adobe's DNG converter which converts new raw types to an old common format named DNG that holds a big part of the raw information.

What you could make with a raw developer better than the automatic development process in the camera? Automatic systems often guess wrong. You may want totally different

- white balance (your example is very badly yellow as far as I can see)
- brightness values that are selected to be black and white in jpg
- boost of details (=local contrast)
- overall contrast
- color saturation

Typically a JPG can have too dark or bright areas, but in raw development program one can make much better jpgs with manual adjustments.

The following is of course a fake, but something like it is often possible easily in the raw developer - at least if the camera has high quality sensor with high dynamic range:

[image]

Watch tutorials to learn "how to"!

ADD: Removal of the background is not possible in the raw development process. That work needs an already developed photo. And work means manual work with eraser, masks or clipping tools - no automatic ways still developed.

Comment: hello, what you mean it is a fake?

Comment: @S.Redrum the example image in the answer is an edited JPG to show you the type of thing you can do with a true RAW file, but since we don’t have the true RAW file it is only a “fake” example (for a “real” example we would need access to the RAW file).

Comment: @S.Redrum the explanation seems already given. If you häd given a link to the real raw image, I of course would have tried it.

Comment: @user287001 i though this was a raw file

Comment: @S.Redrum your photo file is a little more than 2 megabytes. A raw file with the same pixel dimensions can easily take 10...20 x more.. Try to find the raw file from your phone if it really saves raws. I have no idea where it is, how it's named or does it even exist.

Comment: @user287001 I have no idea then, just sent my phone for repair a day ago :(